# Mercurial-server and apache

Tags: apache, mercurial

Currently, I can push my repositories to CentOS server (example.com) through ssh to /var/lib/mercurial-server/repos/SOMEREPO using hgadmin.
Is there a way to access SOMEREPO via example.com/SOMEREPO ?

Answer (score 0):

There are [a lot of ways](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) how you can publish your repositories.

If you're familiar with apache, the probably simplest solution is to use hgweb.cgi which is a cgi script that comes with the mercurial distribution.

An in-depth step-by-step guide how to setup hgweb can be found at the [mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) . Since you mentioned CentOS, you probably want to check out the [hgweb setup guide for RHEL4](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RHEL4HgWebDirSetup).

If you're looking for more complete web-based tools to manage your repositories you may want to look into [SCM-Manager](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SCM-Manager) or [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/).

Comment: What I mean wasn't a "Repository manager with web interface". What I meant was web PAGE which can be accessed via domain.com and pushed/pulled as a repository and updated at the same time. :/
It's almost working for me now, but the problem is that the HOOK doesn't execute line "changegroup = hg update" but every other line works.